# Automatic generate Swagger documentation from Java

Tags: java, rest, documentation, swagger

I have this REST service:

```
@RestController
public class ContaCorrenteController {

    @Autowired
    private configCorrenteService service;

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RequestMapping("/v1/number/{number}/config/{config}/final/{data}")
    @GET
    public ResponseEntity<Final> Final(
            @PathVariable("number") Integer number, 
            @PathVariable("config") Integer config, 
            @PathVariable("data") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyyMMdd") LocalDate data) {
        Final final = service.consultFinal(number, config, data);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(final);
    }

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RequestMapping("/v1/number/{number}/config/{config}/final")
    @GET
    public ResponseEntity<Final> final(
            @PathVariable("number") Integer number, 
            @PathVariable("config") Integer config) {
        Final final = service.consultFinalNow(number, config);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(final);
    }
}
```

I need to automatically genarete a REST documentation using this java file.
Can I automatically generate a json or yaml to import on Swagger editor or another way to documentation?

Comment: Please see here; https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup

Comment: Think this will be helpful https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate with SpringFox:

https://github.com/springfox/springfox

Which can automatically generate swagger definitions from your Spring-MVC server.  You'll need to add some annotations to effectively document things but it should be quite straight forward.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer...
Could you explain what is the difference between Swagger-Core and Springfox?
May I use only Swagger-Core to automatic generating the Swagger documentation?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Springfox is a community-driven project to add swagger support to spring-mvc.  Swagger core is focused on pure servlets and JAX-RS